# unsequenced modification and access to pointer

Tags: c, prefix-operator

I'm getting a warning for this C expression:

```
*p0++ = mult(*p0, psign[i1]);
```

The warning is:

```
unsequenced modification and access to 'p0' [-Wunsequenced]
```

I think the expression should be modified to this:

```
*p0 = mult(*p0, psign[i1]);
p0++;
```

Is the behavior (after modification) going to be as intended? I would think that the pointer increment should happen after the value pointed to by p0 has been updated.

Comment: Does the warning go away?

Comment: The warning goes away, but I am not sure the behavior is the same. So I was looking for a confirmation on that

Comment: What behavior do you _want_? The warning was because the behavior you're going to get might not be what you want (it's undefined), where the change you propose makes it pretty clear that `p0` will be the return of `mult()` and then incremented.

Comment: @mah: I am not sure because this is code that I didn't write. It's G.729 source code.

Comment: @user1884325 I believe it's safe to make the change since the alternative, leaving the code as it is, yields undefined behavior. That said, you should certainly test well after such a change if its impact is important to you.

Comment: Is `mult()` a macro here?

Comment: No - it's a function. The source is here --> http://g729.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/acelp_ca.c

Comment: @user1884325; I think there is a serious bug in the code you have posted. Several lines in that code have the same problem that I mentioned in my answer. It need to be fixed.

Comment: @haccks: Yes, there are like 6-8 cases..

Comment: Ridiculous code.  Why would anyone write garbage like that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The snippet you have provided above invokes undefined behavior. According to C standard

#### C11: 6.5 Expressions:

> **If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to** either a different side effect on the same scalar object or **a value computation using the value of the same scalar object**, the behavior is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.<sup>84)</sup>.

In the expression `*p0++ = mult(*p0, psign[i1])`, the modification to `p0` on left side of the assignment operator is not sequenced before or after the use of `p0` on right hand side of the expression. Therefore, the snippet

```
*p0++ = mult(*p0, psign[i1]);
```

is not equivalent to

```
*p0 = mult(*p0, psign[i1]);
p0++;                       // Side effect to p0 is guaranteed after the use  
                            // of p0 in mult function
```

Comment: In layman's terms, you know that you need to read `*p0` in order to form the input parameter to `mult()`, and the problem is it is not defined when that address will be read: before the incrementation, or after. Compile the same code using different compilers (even different versions of the same compiler) and it's possible you'll get different results.

Comment: but most likely what the author intended was to multiply 2 numbers using the value pointed to by p0 and after the result has been stored in the memory location which p0 points to, then as a final operation increment the pointer by 1??

Comment: @user1884325 that's how it seems to me

Comment: @user1884325; Which part of the answer is not clear to you? I think you know what is meant by "unsequenced" in this context.

Comment: @user1884325: In layman's terms: the old code was 'undefined behaviour' and you can't predict what would actually happen.  The proposed revised code has fully defined behaviour (or, at the least, the use of `*p0` is clean, and the modification of `p0` is also clean), so it is an improvement over the original.  Since the original code had undefined behaviour, you won't be able to write code 100% compatible with it. You can, however, write code that does what the author probably intended, and that's what the proposed rewrite does. So, assuming the warning is no longer emitted, you're good to go.

Comment: @haccks : Yes, I know what the word sequence means. It's a word that can be used in many different contexts and context may (or may not) have an impact on how things should be interpreted in the individual case.

Comment: Thank you everybody for the fast responses :-) Appreciate it!

Comment: @user1884325: The standard is [quite clear](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p3) about the meaning.