# error: unsequenced modification and access to <argument>

Tags: c, gcc, clang

In this code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SHIFT(value,num_of_bits) ((num_of_bits) > 0) ? \
                ((value) <<= (num_of_bits)) : ((value) >>= (-(num_of_bits)))

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int w1 = 0177777u, w2 = 0444u;

    printf("SHIFT(w1,5) = %o\tw1 << 5 = %o\n", SHIFT(w1,5), w1 << 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Here when I use **clang** to compile, I get the following error:

error: unsequenced modification and access to w1

But when I compile it using **gcc**, no errors are generated.

I saw this question here [unsequenced modification and access to pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017561/unsequenced-modification-and-access-to-pointer) but the answers didn't help actually. So I don't get it, why this is happening ? and what does that error mean ?

Comment: There is no sequence point between the evaluation of the separate parameters you pass to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are trying to modify the first argument `value` in the definition of `SHIFT`. Try to modify the macro as follows:

```
#define SHIFT(value,num_of_bits) ((num_of_bits) > 0) ? \
                ((value) << (num_of_bits)) : ((value) >> (-(num_of_bits)))
```

Comment: But why that error was generated by **clang** and was not generated when I compiled using **gcc** ?

Comment: It's because of the difference of static analysis capabilities of the compilers. In this case, clang seems to be more accurate than gcc. The printf call has several arguments including a side-effect: the 2nd one modifies w and the 3rd one reads w. Therefore, the result may be different depending on the order of the evaluations of the arguments and clang is just warning about it.